# Birthdays not displayed initially

Tags: contacts, 6.0-marshmallow, calendar

Just received my Honor 7 and imported my outlook.com stuff to a corporate account. Everything is imported and working correctly, except that birthdays are not displayed in the calendar.

They do get displayed after I remove them from a contact, save, and then add them back in. This is a lot of work so I'm hoping someone can suggest a better alternative?